# Blockchain.info's blockcount API call giving error, alternatives?

Tags: api, blockchain.info

This URL today: https://blockchain.info/q/getblockcount

Was giving the error "Too many requests".

Any alternative out there to get the blockcount via an API? Thanks

Comment: Works fine for me (5 minutes after you posted your question).

Answer (score 2):

Another public API I found for this:

https://blockexplorer.com/api/status?q=getBlockCount

But the best one so far, is blockR.io because it even has testnet support:

MainNet: http://btc.blockr.io/api/v1/coin/info

TestNet: http://tbtc.blockr.io/api/v1/coin/info

Answer (score 0):

You can use our API:

Get latest block (total blocks count )

https://bitaps.com/api/#Get_latest_block

Comment: testnet support?